# Switch existing Amplify app to new repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to switch the repository of an Amplify App to use a new one by creating a new Amplify App and copying over all the settings, but I am running into the issue below whenever I try to proceed through the sign up flow, which is using AWS cognito. I have not had any other issues than this one and have copied over everything nearly one-to-one, and not had this problem in the old project.

AuthError -
Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

```
        1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
            See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

        2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```